# adding extra dropdown in register form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i am modifying a social script and we want to add extra field in registration form for job :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="job">{__("My Job")}</label>
<select name="job" id="job" class="form-control" required>
<option value="none">{__("Select Job")}:</option>
<option value="designer">{__("designer")}</option>
<option value="programmer">{__("programmer")}</option>
<option value="it">{__("it")}</option>
<option value="coder">{__("coder")}</option>
```

i tried many things to add the extra field to be added to the database but it always give me an error in registration page : http://doctown.net/signup

and this script has a user class file can be downloaded from here : http://doctown.net/class-user.zip

so i tried to use :

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
{
$aJob = $_POST['user_Job'];
if(!isset($ajob)) 
{
echo("<p>You didn't select any job!</p>\n");
} 
else
{
$nJob = count($ajob);
echo("<p>You selected $nJob job: ");
for($i=0; $i < $nJob; $i++)
{
echo($aJob[$i] . " ");
}
echo("</p>");
}
}
```

but it didnt work and many many other ways without any luck

what the function should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get:

```
$aJob = $_POST['job'];
```

instead

And please take note that if the doesn't select job, the job parameter is 'none'

BTW:

```
$nJob = count($ajob);
```

This may not work as the user could only select 1 job.  The data sent to the server is a string

Comment: nope ... 
  if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
{
$aJob = $_POST['job'];
if(!isset($ajob)) 
{
echo("<p>You didn't select any job!</p>\n");
} 
else
{
$nJob = count($ajob);
echo("<p>You selected $nJob job: ");
for($i=0; $i < $nJob; $i++)
{
echo($aJob[$i] . " ");
}
echo("</p>");
}
}


An error occurred while writing to database. Please try again later

Comment: Seems like something is wrong when u are saving the user info.  try var_dump(someValue); at different point and see where the issue is